# Proving/disproving a given set $A$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
Let $(\R^2, d)$, where $d$ denotes the usual Euclidean distance, be a metric space. A set $A$ is defined as follows:

$$A = \left\{ (x,y) \in \R^2 \; \middle| \; e^{2x} + \left( \frac y 5 \right)^4 < 1 \right\}$$

I think the set should be open in this metric space.

To prove it, is it correct to show the boundary set of $A$ is a subset of $\R^2\setminus A$?

Let $P_0(x_0,y_0)$ be an arbitrary element belongs to the boundary set.

There exists a converging sequence in $A$ that converge to $P_0$.

Also, there exists a converging sequence in the complement of $A$ that is also converging to $P_0$.

Then we have for all $n>N$ for some $N$,

$$e^{2x_n} + \left( \frac {y_n} 5 \right)^4 \ge 1$$

And since the sequence when $n \to \infty$ is $P_0 (x_0,y_0)$.

So after taking the limit we have

$$e^{2x_0} + \left( \frac {y_0} 5 \right)^4 \ge 1$$

Thus $P_0$ is a element of $\R^2\setminus A$.

Does my proof make sense?

Comment: take the function $f(x,y)=\exp(2x)+(\frac{y}{5})^4$ this function is continuous and $A=f^{-1}((\infty,)[$ wich is the inverse image of an open set by a continuous function so $A$ is open

Comment: the problem with your proof is that you show that $A$ is not a closed set, but this doesn't mean $A$ is open, for example, take $(0,1]$ which is not open and not a closed set

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get your first comment, what do you mean by the inverse images of open sets, of continuous functions?

Comment: it's just $f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$

Answer (score 4):

There's another approach:
To answer your main question, what do you know of inverse images of open sets, of continuous functions?

Is the given function continuous?
And is (-∞,1) open in R?

Answer (score 0):

It is a correct approach. In any topological space $X$ and any $A\subseteq X,$ with $A^c= X$ \ $A,$ the sets $int(A),\, int(A^c), \,\partial A$ are pairwise-disjoint and their union is $X.$

Now $int(A)$ is the union of all subsets of $A$ (including possibly $A$ itself) that are open in the space $X,$ so $int (A)$ is open and $int (A)\subseteq A.$

If $A\cap \partial A=\phi$ then $$A=A\cap X=(A \cap int (A))\,\cup\, (A\cap A^c)\,\cup\, (A\cap \partial A)=(int(A))\cup (\phi)\cup (\phi)=int (A)$$ so $A$  is open.